# How to repeat a App script function for only certain column

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have written this JS function in google sheet

```
=calculateCallLoss(D3, D2:D65, B2:B65, A2:A65)
```

Now I want to repeat this function in a column but only first param should increment e.g in next row it should be like

```
=calculateCallLoss(D4, D2:D65, B2:B65, A2:A65)
```

If I try to copy-paste and repeat it then other params are touched as well which should remain constant in every row.

Can you please share how to achieve this?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed 3 modification patterns. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and those were not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification? In this modification,

#### Modified formula:

```
=calculateCallLoss(D3, $D$2:$D$65, $B$2:$B$65, $A$2:$A$65)
```

or

```
=calculateCallLoss(D3, INDIRECT("D2:D65"), INDIRECT("B2:B65"), INDIRECT("A2:A65"))
```

or

```
=BYROW(D3:D,LAMBDA(ROW, calculateCallLoss(ROW, D2:D65, B2:B65, A2:A65)))
```

- In this case, please put this into a cell. By this, `D3:D` is used.

#### Note:

- Although I'm not sure about your actual script of `calculateCallLoss`, I thought that in your situation, your goal might be able to be achieved by modifying your current script.

Comment: I used the =calculateCallLoss(D3, $D$2:$D$65, $B$2:$B$65, $A$2:$A$65) and it worked, Thank you.

Comment: @Tarun Chawla Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.